# How can I apply this function in a correct way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I’m working on a dataset I found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-city/nyc-property-sales).

I tried to write a function to convert each value of column BOROUGH from digit to names.
Like this:

```
# Manhattan (1), Bronx (2), Brooklyn (3), Queens (4), and Staten Island (5)

## convert BOROUGHS from int to string

df['BOROUGH'] = df['BOROUGH'].astype(str)

## create a function to replace number with name

def name_boro(s):
    if s == '1':
        return 'Manhattan'
    elif s == '2':
        return 'Bronx'
    elif s == '3':
        return 'Brooklyn'
    elif s == '4':
        return 'Queens'
    else:
        return 'Staten Island'
    
df.apply(name_boro(df['BOROUGH']))
```

The output message is this:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 19         return 'Staten Island'
> 20
> ---> 21 df.apply(name_boro(df['BOROUGH']))
>
> in name_boro(s)
> 8
> 9 def name_boro(s):
> ---> 10     if s == '1':
> 11         return 'Manhattan'
> 12     elif s == '2':
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> **nonzero**(self)    1327     1328     def **nonzero**(self):
> -> 1329         raise ValueError(    1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "    1331
> "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Would like to help me?

Thank you,
Giovanni

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large df, it is not worth using an `apply` method.
Instead, you could use a `map` method as follows:

```
# define your dictionary
num_to_name = {'1': 'Manhattan', '2': 'Bronx', '3': 'Brooklyn', '4': 'Queens'}
# map the values in BOROUGH column
df['BOROUGH'] = df['BOROUGH'].map(num_to_name)
```

Comment: It's correct that this `map` method would probably run faster than using `apply` with custom function, especially for large dataset.  So better retain to emphasize this point.   Upvoted, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['BOROUGH'] = df['BOROUGH'].apply(name_boro)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`, but using a default value. BTW, you do not need to convert the original numbers to strings.

```py
df.BOROUGH.map(lambda x: {1: 'Manhattan', 2: 'Bronx', 3: 'Brooklyn', 4: 'Queens'}.get(x, 'Staten Island'))
```